# Grub rescue insmod normal fails

Tags: boot, grubrescue, debian

My system has a Ubuntu 20.04 installation and a Debian 9 installation
Because I installed debian after ubuntu grub was installed from debian which was fine with me.
Recently I decided to remove the debian installation since I didnt need it anymore so I removed the partition and rebooted without running update-grub or grub-install
I am now in a grub rescue shell and I have successfully found my boot folder and when I do

```
set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,5)
```

I can now do ls /boot and see everything.
The problem is, when I enter

```
insmod normal
```

I get

```
error: symbol ‘grub_file_filters’ not found.
```

Same thing when I specify the path to the module.

Some research later it seems that the grub installed by debian is incompatible with the normal mod from ubuntu and I can’t boot my system this way.

The problem is, I have no way of getting any type of rescue stick since I’m on vacation with only my laptop and no stick.

Is there any way that I can still boot somehow or do I absolutely need a live installation to fix this?

Comment: Is install EFI or legacy boot? If Efi, you only need to configure boot-order in UEFI-settings to use Grub installed by Ubuntu.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is legacy boot. Do I understand correctly that in EFI boot I can select the grub bootloader on the ubuntu partition? Because there is not other grub in the MBR afaik it got overwritten by debian.

Comment: In EFI systems bootloaders coexist in the ESP ( EFI System Partition) but different folders. Since you use legacy boot, that's not helpful for you. You'll need a bootable pendrive or a DVD to be able to reinstall Grub.

Comment: Sorry for getting back this late, in all honesty, I just forgot about my post. I have since fixed the problem with a bootable stick. During boot however GRUB displayed something about EFI, so I don't know if my system is in fact EFI. Apart from the problem that my BIOS gives no conclusive information about itself, in case it is EFI, how would I go about such a problem in the future?